# error: ‘result’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, vector

I want to find minimum value in my data set.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <iterator>  


int main(){
std::vector<double> v;
std::ifstream inputFile1("263_V01_C02_R099_THx_BL_128H.dat");

if (inputFile1) {        
    double value;
    while ( inputFile1 >> value ) {
        v.push_back(value);
    }
}

auto result = std::min_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v));

}
```

I have seen previous responses,people point to iterator not being included.How to solve this?

Comment: It has nothing at all to do with `<iterator>` being included.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @GCC Works fine now,thanks!

Comment: Answers don't go in questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auto` is a **C++11** specifier. You need a C++11 compiler.

With **gcc** you can enable the C++11 features using `-std=c++11`:

gcc exaple:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto)

> **auto specifier (since C++11)** 
>   Specifies that the type of the variable that is being declared will be automatically deduced from its initializer.

If you don't have a C++11 compiler, then you need to define the concrete type.
Eg:

```
std::vector<double>::iterator result = ...
```

BTW: `std::begin()` and `std::end()` are also C++11 features.

Comment: How do you know GCC is being used? And that it is of a sufficient version to support `auto` with this flag?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes,I am compiling with gcc,works fine now!

Comment: @RichardRublev: Please include that critical detail in your question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit gcc was just an example.

Answer (score 2):

As sergej already pointed out `auto` is a C++11 specifier/keyword.

If you don't have access to a C++11 compiler you could still use this to make your code work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <iterator>  


int main() {
    std::vector<double> v;
    std::ifstream inputFile1("263_V01_C02_R099_THx_BL_128H.dat");

    if (inputFile1) {
        double value;
        while (inputFile1 >> value) {
            v.push_back(value);
        }
    }

    double result = 0; //Or other default value
    std::vector<double>::iterator minIter = std::min_element(v.begin(), v.end());
    if (minIter != v.end())
    {
        result = (*minIter);
    }
    std::cout << "Result is " << result << std::endl;

}
```

**Additional hint:**

`auto` in your code is the same as `std::vector<double>::iterator` in this case. So you will have an iterator as result.

You should always check an return value iterator against `.end()` before using it.

**EDIT**:
Using `v.begin()` and `v.end()` instead of `std::begin(v)` and `std::end(v)` as pointed out by sergej and NathanOliver.

Comment: `std::begin()` and `std::end()` are C++11 functions